# 17.10 VLC video wallpaper covers dock

Tags: gnome, vlc, 17.10

I've just upgraded to Ubuntu 17.10, and subsequently I'm now using GNOME instead of Unity. However I have a video wallpaper using VLC which worked with Unity, this doesn't work so well with the GNOME environment as the video covers the dock. Is there a way to have the video wallpaper not cover the dock.

I'm starting the wallpaper with the following command:

```
vlc --no-video-on-top --video-wallpaper --zoom 2 --no-osd --no-audio --qt-start-minimized --qt-notification 0 --qt-system-tray http://iphone-streaming.ustream.tv/uhls/9408562/streams/live/iphone/playlist.m3u8
```